# Cloudflare bypass with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cloudflare

I'm trying to enter hotbit.io, with my Puppeteer. But I'm met with "Checking your browser before accessing www.hotbit.io" the moment puppeteer tries entering the page.
When I run my program in "headless: false" it redirects to the page after 5 seconds. But my problem is, that I want to run it in headless: true.
When I run it in headless: true, it timesout on the cloudflare page
[Screenshot at timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3A04.jpg)

I have tried:

- "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth"
- "Cloudflare-scraper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudflare-scraper)". This has very limited documentation (non-existing), but I saw under "Issues" on their github, that it is not supported anymore.

It seems like, that cloudflare knows, that I'm having headless activated.

Does anyone know, how I can skip the cloudflare redirecting page?

Comment: You require a header to tell cloudflare who you are.

Comment: setUserAgent() should be a start to your solution, GL!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thank you @BGPHiJACK !

It helped by setting user agent to: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0

So right after I have init the page, I set user agent.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
    
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0')
```

Comment: Be aware this will not necessarily always work. CloudFlare's scraper protection systems update frequently. Long-term, you may want to coordinate a deal with the site you're accessing for uninterrupted access.

Comment: Just to emphasize, i used chrome as userAgent and it did not work , so make sure you used latest firefox version as of today it should be `await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0')`

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare has been updated and now plugin like puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth or changing UserAgent doesn't work. There is a module in npm that allows me to access cloudflare protected sites. https://www.npmjs.com/package/antibotbrowser