# How do I by pass Cloudflare check box/security check in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How do I by pass Cloudflare check box/security check in puppeteer? for example if I run my script it automaticity check the Cloudflare check box and pass the security check.

Is it possible to do this in any way in Node.js? I've been trying to use User-agent too but it didn't work out. I also discovered "antibotbrowser" package from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/77853159/23575116 but that also is not working in my case.

```
import { startbrowser } from "antibotbrowser";
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
    const antibrowser = await startbrowser();

    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: antibrowser.websokcet,
        headless: false, 
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36');

    await page.goto("https://www.doordash.com");

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

    const title = await page.title();
    console.log("Page title:", title);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Not sure, but thats the whole point of a captcha/protection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [issue comment](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/817#issuecomment-1974854105), I tried the adding the line `targetFilter: (target) => target.type() !== "other"` to the `puppeteer.launch` and it seems to work

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    targetFilter: (target) => target.type() !== "other",
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.doordash.com");

})();
```

If it does not work for you, check other comments on the issue, seems like a tricky problem